# How to remove the title property of an avi video

Tags: video

There has been a similar question asked, but the answer does not work for my situation.  I have a .avi video which has the title of Video_DVD.  This is not the correct title of the video and does not correctly display the file name in inventory search.  I am using Windows 8.1 and have a number of video players, but none of them provide for ignoring or deleting the title.  There are 12 videos in this series, but only 2 of them have the title Video_DVD.  The remainder have no title listed and thus inventory with the file name.  This makes determining in which sequence the videos should be played difficult to impossible

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file in [VirtualDub](https://www.virtualdub.org)
- Set video and audio to `Direct stream copy`
- Choose <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Set text information</kbd>
- Scroll down until you find the field that is set to `Video_DVD` and change it
- Save a new AVI (<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Save as AVI</kbd>)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [abcAVI](http://abcavi.kibi.ru/) tool. It works fine in W7-W10 despite mentioned OS`es on official website.

However it doesn`t work with files >2Gb.